# What is the benefit of dealing cards when being the player with the least points in Zombie Life?

Tags: zombie-life

In the game "Zombie Life", if you are the player with the lowest points, the rules state that you have to deal the cards for the next round. However, what is the benefit of this action ?

With friends with whom I played with, we tried that this "last" player could **choose** to whom the cards will be dealt to, so that the rule would have a meaning...

What is the correct rule here ?

Comment: It sounds like there is no benefit; instead it is a minor chore that one would want to avoid.  It is extra incentive to not be the player with the lowest points.